# Config nginx for Laravel In a subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have and old project that now requires new functionality, I'm going to use laravel to provide it,
everything in working ok in xampp with apache but my server con nginx show me access denied message and cant access my routes, how should be my site config should be if laravel is installed in mysite.com/2015 my site config is the following, what showld I change?
I have tried

```
location /newsection/ { 
   try_files $uri $uri/ /newsection/public/index.php$request_uri;
}
```

but it causes 500 error

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name am2.aminversiones.com;
    root /home/forge/am2.aminversiones.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 300M;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/am2.aminversiones.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # version 1
    location ^~ /2015 {
        alias /home/forge/am2.aminversiones.com/2015/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @2015;
        location ~* \.php {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location @2015 {
        rewrite ^/2015/(.*)$ /2015/index.php/$1 last; # THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE
    }
    # end version 1

    # version 2
    # this is with `ln -s /home/tom/public_html/demos/demo1/public <document root>/demo1`
    location ~ /2015 {
        try_files /2015/$uri /2015/$uri/ /2015/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    # end version 2

    # PHP FPM configuration.
    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include                             /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index                       index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info             ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO             $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED       $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME       $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Well, I found a solution to very easy config and install Laravel in a subdirectory in a nginx server, in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourSite config file, add this:

```
location ^~ /laravel {
    alias /var/www/laravel/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location @laravel {
    rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

and voila, your routes will work normally how they should.

Comment: This fixed an issue i had for a few days now. Thanks

Comment: This works great, but if I do:

http://www.example.org/laravel/?var=12345 it will give me an 404 error. 

Any ideas how to solve it, regards!

Comment: @Alberto make sure to reload nginx and php5-fpm

Comment: That's not working. it forces php files to download than to be served

Answer (score 21):

after I spend some hours on this issue, finally I fixed my problem with a subdomain address like this:

If you want to put your `laravel` project in a `subfolder` on a server with `ngnix-ubuntu 16-php.7.2`, so here is the ngnix config :

1. your nested(subfolder) isn't inside your main folder

   /var/www/main:
   /var/www/nested:

then your config should be :

```
location /nested {

        alias /var/www/nested/public;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

               location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                                }
   }

location @nested {
        rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

2. The laravel-test folder (subfolder) inside the main folder :

   /var/www/main:
   /var/www/main/nested:

then your config should be :

```
location /laravel-test {

    alias /var/www/main/laravel-test/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelTest;

           location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                            }


  }

location @laravelTest {
        rewrite /laravel-test/(.*)$ /laravel-test/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option works.
And why ```rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/index.php?/$1 last;``` but not ```rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/public/index.php?/$1 last;``` ?

Comment: There is no difference between the 2 config

Comment: Now that's an answer. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: i had an issue with the above method, as nginx would append an extra parameter {url path} to my query string when sending an ajax post request

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I was searching a lot for a solution of this problem.

Comment: That solution didn't worked for me. I put whole laravel project to trash and try to create from scratch using just html and js

Comment: I am happy to report that I tried this and it worked. I am running Homestead which uses nginx.

Comment: css or js file showing 404 Error.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see the difference between the two?

Answer (score 10):

This is the workaround that solved my problem
With alias, Nginx does NOT look for files within /var/www/portal/public/portal/foo, like it would with the root directive

```
location /portal {
 alias /var/www/html/portal/public; #preferred over root

 # @portal is a named location
 try_files $uri $uri/ @portal;

 location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
 }
}

location @portal {
rewrite /portal/(.*)$ /portal/index.php last; # Remove ?/$1 since fastcgi_params adds query string
}
```

Additional reference can be found from this article https://gist.github.com/tsolar/8d45ed05bcff8eb75404

Comment: This is the only answer I found on the whole internet and beyond that works. The most important part is: remove `?/$1`. Don't remove it and your query strings will all fail miserably. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my case, this worked because other nginx.conf suggestions use  `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`, however it was the use of  `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` which finally fixed my server and brought me peace of mind .

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Removing these 4 characters `?/$1`works well for me. Up until some Laravel 8 update my system worked well with these characters, then Laravel added `$request->server->get('QUERY_STRING')` to the evaluation of a signed route, which got my system into problems. Solved now.

Comment: This works great for me - Laravel 9 and PHP 8.1 on NGINX 1.22. With the other solutions I can't access the Laravel's API.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason for me, the alias was causing the issue and didn't work.
So maybe this will help others, so here is what I did to make this work.
As you can see I took the "alias" out of it and added laravel/public to the equation.

```
location ^~ /laravel/public {
            index home.php home.html home.htm index.html index.htm index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
            charset utf-8;

            location ~ \.php {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                include fastcgi_params;
            }
        }
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location @laravel {
       rewrite /laravel/public/(.*)$ /laravel/public/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
```

Comment: For more clear and constructive answer, you can add more details on how and why the solution is working for you to make it more understandable. With that, keep it up and thanks for sharing your possible solution to the problem :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work with the alias I don't fully understand how the Nginx configuration works. I'm not sure either of the difference it makes with or without alias.

Answer (score 1):

it did not work for me, so I got another solution.

1. I had created a "normal" laravel domain, point to http://generic.laravel
   root /my/laravel/path/public
2. After that, I created a location on real domain proxying to my generic Laravel:

   ```
   location /laravel {
       rewrite /laravel/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://generic.laravel;
   ```

   }
3. Unfortunately, Laravel is going to use the url http://generic.laravel to create links. You may to solve it following this steps [Laravel: Change base URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304448/laravel-change-base-url)

Answer (score 0):

I have met several case like error 403 or 404, and I think this method works. Don't forget to change php version based on your php version in server (`php8.1-fpm.sock`). Note `your_domain www.your_domain` is based on your website.

```
   server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name your_domain www.your_domain;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /yourlaravelproject {
        alias /var/www/html/yourlaravelproject/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

after you configure, don't forget to add this to your symlink, then `systemctl restart nginx`. I'm sure for Laravel 8 and 9 still works, because I just recently test Laravel 9 project in subfolder and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the server directive, specify the public folder in the root parameter

in file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/am2.aminversiones.com`

```
server {
    ...
    root /home/forge/am2.aminversiones.com/public;
    ...
}
```

restart the nginx service: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Answer (score -2):

location /stationery { alias /var/www/html/stationery/public; try_files $uri $uri/ @stationery; location ~ .php$ { include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename; } }

location @stationery{ rewrite /stationery/(.*)$ /stationery/index.php?/ last; }

Comment: Please add some description to the answer you have provided.