# nginx, install laravel in main website sub directory, shows blank page

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am running nginx. The current setup is

main_site.local (main site)
physical path: /var/www/html/test/testme/bla/main_site/public_html

main_site.local/laravel
physical path: /var/www/html/test/testme/bla/main_site/public_html/laravel/public

Based on this: [Config nginx for Laravel In a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785372/config-nginx-for-laravel-in-a-subfolder)

I have

```
server {
  listen 81;
  #listen   [::]:81 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

  root /var/www/html/test/testme/bla/main_site/public_html; 
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  server_name main_site.local;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; 
  }


    location ^~ /laravel {
        alias /var/www/html/test/testme/bla/main_site/public_html/laravel/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

      location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      }
    }

    location @laravel {
        rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
    }


  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
```

when i hit main_site.local/laravel, it shows a blank page, not the laravel welcome page.

I put a die in /var/www/html/test/testme/bla/main_site/public_html/laravel/public/index.php, it doesn't execute.

**Update 1**

Based on this: https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/nginx-config-for-hosting-multiple-projects-in-sibling-folders/

I have

```
server {
    listen  81;
    root /var/www/html/test/testme/igloo/igloosof/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php app.php app_dev.php;

    server_name main-site.local;

    charset utf-8;

    location /laravel{
        rewrite ^/laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/public/index.php?$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Error:
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
I am accessing the default laravel home page (the welcome page)

Comment: location ~ \.php remove the location in laravel location. and use `try_files ` no rewrite. and you index.php in public folder location

Answer (score 4):

Incase you still havn't solved this, try adding `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` to in location->php block of your first example.

Here is how I setup-ed my `location` block which is working for me perfectly:

```
location ^~ /facebookschedule {  
alias /home/netcans/facebookschedule/public;  
try_files $uri $uri/ @foobar;  

location ~ \.php {  
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;  
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;  
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;  
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/wwww/facebookschedule/public/index.php;  
}  
}  

location @foobar {  
rewrite /facebookschedule/(.*)$ /facebookschedule/index.php?/$1 last;  
}
```

I was also getting similar White Screen (blank page) and 404 errors related to route not found but was able to fix everything following the full Nginx Conf file example from this post:
http://shubhank.gaur.io/setup-laravel-5-in-subfolder-with-nginx/

Answer (score 2):

It's maybe because about your ngnix config. in two way you can check config :

If you want to put your `laravel` project in a `subfolder` on a server with `ngnix-ubuntu 16-php.7.2`, so here is update ngnix config :

1) your nested(subfolder) isn't inside your main folder

```
/var/www/main:
/var/www/nested:
```

then your config :

```
location /nested {

        alias /var/www/nested/public;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

               location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                                }
   }

location @nested {
        rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

2) your laravel-test folder (subfolder) inside your main :

```
/var/www/main:
/var/www/main/nested:
```

then your config :

```
location /laravel-test {

    alias /var/www/main/laravel-test/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelTest;

           location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                            }


  }

location @laravelTest {
        rewrite /laravel-test/(.*)$ /laravel-test/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came to using Nginx 1.13 and PHP-7.2 after googling for hours.

Writeup/full explanation on [putting a php app in a subdirectory here](https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory).

Three important parts are:

1. figuring out what `root` vs `alias` is doing
2. Using a named `location` block to do the `rewrite` successfully
3. Finding a way to not have to hard-code FastCGI's `SCRIPT_FILENAME`

Here's the solution I came to (note the apps live in different locations on the disk drive):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/top/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /nested {
        alias /var/www/nested/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location @nested {
        rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```