# Hosting two Laravel projects on one domain or sub-domain?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, nginx-config

I have two Laravel projects and using NGINX webserver. However, since they related, I would want to use one sub-domain for both.

How do I set up this?

I have tried researching on this to no avail.

Anyone assist on this?

Comment: One would presumably be in a subfolder?

Comment: @ceejayoz how exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785372/config-nginx-for-laravel-in-a-subfolder

Answer (score 0):

use separate nginx config files for each, pointing to their own folders.

Directory structure

/var

..└── /www

....└── /first_laravel_app

....└── /second_laravel_app

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # For https
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;

    server_name {subdomain}.{domain}.com;
    root /var/www/wesdesk/{folder}/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_access.log;
}
```

In the above config example replace the {subdomain} {domain} and {folder} with the respective values. You should have two nginx config files, one for each site, each with it's own values. Make sure to restart nginx after creating the new configs as well.