# Laravel in a sub-directory using NGINX with preserved routing

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-7

I'm currently trying to install a Laravel app in a sub-directory of a site using nginx to direct any traffic to that app.

I have followed the suggestions in the following Stackoverflow question, and it works perfectly [Config nginx for Laravel In a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785372/config-nginx-for-laravel-in-a-subfolder)

However, when using this method it removes the need for the sub-directory to be in the Laravel apps routes.

**An example.**

Say I am pointing all requests to https://example.com/shop to a /shop subdirectory using the following nginx entry...

```
location /shop {
    alias /var/www/shop/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @shop;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location @shop {
    rewrite /shop/(.*)$ /shop/index.php last;
}
```

As stated, this works but the route for the shops "homepage" in the app will actually be

```
Route::get('/', ShopController::class)->name('shop.home');
```

Whereas I need it to be

```
Route::get('/shop', ShopController::class)->name('shop.home');
```

I don't have control over all the routing etc due to it being in packages, and there are various other reasons why this would be preferable for me anyway.

Is there a way to adapt the above nginx entry to achieve this? I have tried numerous things but can not seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doe's sub-domain can be ok for you? I posted some examples you can try ... but probably sub-domain https://shop.website.com will solve all of our issues :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set dynamicaly and change the **fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_url**.

Basically to remove or add (depend on your needs) the word **/shop** from the REQUEST_URI

You may need to remove **REQUEST_URI** from **fastcgi_params** file.

More info and example can found in

https://serverfault.com/questions/697569/rewrite-url-with-fastcgi-in-nginx

I didn't tested it so maybe some changes need to made in some lines or change the order of things...

but you can try to use something like

```
location /shop {
    alias /var/www/shop/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @shop;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /shop$request_uri;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location @shop {
    rewrite /shop/(.*)$ /shop/index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. It still points to / instead of /shop

Answer (score 0):

I got this working thanks to a clue from [@shushu304](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8884892/shushu304)

I just updated the REQUEST_URI using the following.

```
location /shop {
    alias /var/www/shop/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @shop;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /shop$request_uri; <--------
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location @shop {
    rewrite /shop/(.*)$ /shop/index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Cool, this is what i wanted to suggest also (after thinking on it over night :) ) ... any way I updated my example also and you are welcome to vote to my answer :)